# how to get Summary string like google or other search engines

Tags: php, summary

Search engines like google or bing extract a summary from a site description or content when we search a keyword.  I want to write a function that will do the same.

Suppose that I have a site with a post, and the post's content is:

> PHP is a server-side scripting language designed primarily for web
>   development but also used as a general-purpose programming language.
>   Originally created by Rasmus Lerdorf in 1994,[5] the PHP reference
>   implementation is now produced by The PHP Development Team.[6] PHP
>   originally stood for Personal Home Page,[5] but it now stands for the
>   recursive acronym PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor.[7]
>
> PHP code may be embedded into HTML code, or it can be used in
>   combination with various web template systems, web content management
>   systems and web frameworks. PHP code is usually processed by a PHP
>   interpreter implemented as a module in the web server or as a Common
>   Gateway Interface (CGI) executable. The web server combines the
>   results of the interpreted and executed PHP code, which may be any
>   type of data, including images, with the generated web page. PHP code
>   may also be executed with a command-line interface (CLI) and can be
>   used to implement standalone graphical applications.[8]
>
> The standard PHP interpreter, powered by the Zend Engine, is free
>   software released under the PHP License. PHP has been widely ported
>   and can be deployed on most web servers on almost every operating
>   system and platform, free of charge.[9]
>
> The PHP language evolved without a written formal specification or
>   standard until 2014, leaving the canonical PHP interpreter as a de
>   facto standard. Since 2014 work has gone on to create a formal PHP
>   specification.

When I search "php developer designed", I want the function to extract this summary output:

**PHP** is a server-side scripting language **designed** primarily for web development but also used ..... **PHP** allows developers to write extensions in C to add functionality to the PHP language. **PHP** extensions can be compiled statically into PHP or ...

i created this function But not interesting outcome

```
function character_limiter($str, $n = 500, $end_char = '&#8230;')
{
    if (strlen($str) < $n)
    {
        return $str;
    }

    $str = preg_replace("/\s+/", ' ', str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), ' ', $str));

    if (strlen($str) <= $n)
    {
        return $str;
    }

    $out = "";
    foreach (explode(' ', trim($str)) as $val)
    {
        $out .= $val.' ';

        if (strlen($out) >= $n)
        {
            $out = trim($out);
            return (strlen($out) == strlen($str)) ? $out : $out.$end_char;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: what have you done so far and what are you having trouble with?

Comment: Can you clarify your specific question? Currently this question reads like: "How do I make a search engine"

Comment: yes exactly i make a search engin for my site i want when user search a keyword function extract a summary of funded post example: after frist keyword funded from post get 20 character and put ... then After the next keyword get 20 character